# Using loops to change label text with button clicks?

Tags: vb.net

Just started learning Visual Basic..

This works when using loops: box messages pop up until finished

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim d As Integer = 1

    Do While d < 5

        MessageBox.Show("Value: " & d)
        d = d + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

When I want to use it on label text it gives the final output with one click

```
Label2.Text = ("The value of i is: " & i)
```

How can I make it loop only on button click? Do I have to add if statements?

Answer (score 0):

The loop is too fast and the UI updates only when everything in the event is finished. You can add delays to the loop (thread) and force refreshing the UI.

```
    Dim d = 1

    Do While d < 5
        Label1.Text = ("The value of i is: " & d)
        d = d + 1
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Me.Refresh()
    Loop
```

Here, `Thread.Sleep(1000)` creates a delay by pausing the currently running [thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx). The value is in milliseconds. `Me.Refresh()` forces the form to redraw.

This is not the recommended way of handling the problem, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it loop only on button click? Do I have to add if
>   statements?

Sure...you could change your declaration of "d" from `Dim` to `Static`, then use an `If` statement like this:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Static d As Integer = 1

    If d < 5 Then
        Label2.Text = "The value of `d` is: " & d.ToString
        d = d + 1
    End If
End Sub
```